# DevExpress RepositoryItemComboBox BackColor property ignored

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I have the following code which *almost* works properly;

```C#
private void cbStatus_DrawItem(object sender, ListBoxDrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    string item = e.Item as string;
    if (item != null)
    {
        switch (item)
        {
            case "1":
                e.Appearance.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Green;
                break;
            case "2":
                e.Appearance.ForeColor = Color.Orange;
                e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Orange;
                break;
            case "3":
                e.Appearance.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Red;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

When the dropdown is shown, the items forecolor is correct, but the backcolor just remains as whatever the backcolor of the theme is; i.e. if I've got it set to a dark theme, the backcolor is dark, like the cells in the GridView, rather than being Green/Orange/Red.

I've tried setting `e.Appearance.Options.UseBackColor` as well as trying to set `e.Handled` (`e.Handled` breaks forecolor too, so I got rid of that).

Not sure why it's not working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you are set `e.Handled` to `true` then you must draw the items by yourself. For example, you can use [`AppearanceObject.DrawBackground`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressUtilsAppearanceObject_DrawBackgroundtopic(MIswsA)) method and [`AppearanceObject.DrawString`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressUtilsAppearanceObject_DrawStringtopic(a56EwA)) method to draw your items:

```
private void cbStatus_DrawItem(object sender, ListBoxDrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    string item = e.Item as string;
    if (item != null)
    {
        switch (item)
        {
            case "1":
                e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Green;
                break;
            case "2":
                e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Orange;
                break;
            case "3":
                e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Red;
                break;
        }

        e.Appearance.DrawBackground(e.Cache, e.Bounds);
        e.Appearance.DrawString(e.Cache, item, e.Bounds);

        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```